# mark_for_destruction not working on update (nested object) Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have two models with nested attributes: Order and Item. Every order has multiple items.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items,
    :allow_destroy => true
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
end
```

I have a setter method on the Order model to handle operations like update Item attributes, Create new Items, Delete Item, via the Orders views and Controller.

Everything works except for deleting an Item.

I would like to delete an Item when the User enters the :quantity as 0.

This is part of the Instance Setter Method with the logic that handles what I am trying to accomplish (Delete item on the edit order view (update order on controller) when the user enters 0 as the quantity).

```
 elsif item[:id].present? && item[:qty].to_i <= 0
    order_item = self.items.find item[:id]
    order_item.mark_for_destruction
```

if I print order_item.marked_for_destruction? at the end of the elsif, I get true!... The problem is that the order gets successfully updated, but the Item stays there with the previous Quantity.

** UPDATE **

This is the whole setter method on the Order model. This instance method will update item (from Edit Order view), Destroy Item (when Qty = 0), and Create Item (from New Order view) on that order.

```
def items=(items=[])
items.select {|item| item[:id].present? || item[:qty].to_i.positive? }.each do |item|
  if item[:id].present? && item[:qty].to_i.positive?
    order_item = self.items.find item[:id]
    order_item.update quantity:  item[:qty],
                      unit:      item[:unit],
                      catch_weight_data: item[:catch_weight_data],
  elsif item[:id].present? && item[:qty].to_i <= 0
    order_item = self.items.find item[:id]
    order_item.mark_for_destruction
    puts "Was the item marked for destruction?"
    puts order_item.marked_for_destruction?
  else
    next unless item[:qty].to_i.positive?
    lp = LabeledProduct.find item[:labeled_product_id]
    order_item = self.items.new unit_price_in_cents:         lp.price_in_cents,
                                case_price_in_cents:         lp.case_price_in_cents,
                                data:                        lp.data,
                                quantity:                    item[:qty],
                                unit:                        item[:unit],
                                labeled_product_id:          item[:labeled_product_id],
                                customer_labeled_product_id: item[:customer_labeled_product_id],
                                taxable:                     item[:taxable],
                                item_weight:                 item[:item_weight]
   end
  end
 end
```

This is the server log ... I printed Was the Item marked for destruction? and order_item.marked_for_destruction? right after the method that updates items with qty = 0... as you can see it prints as true:

```
Started PATCH "/admin/customers/customer/orders/113" for 127.0.0.1 at 
2018-07-19 10:26:53 -0700
Processing by Admin::Customer::OrdersController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"", "order"=> 
{"status"=>"Submitted", "picked_at"=>"", "fulfilled_at"=>"", "items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"taxable"=>"1", "unit_price"=>"2.47", "id"=>"307"}}, "items"=>[{"id"=>"307", **"qty"=>"0"**, "unit"=>"UNIT", "catch_weight_data"=>["", ""]}...
 "commit"=>"Update Order", "customer_id"=>"customer", "id"=>"113"}
      User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      Customer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "customer"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      Order Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."customer_id" = $1 AND "orders"."id" = $2 ORDER BY "orders"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $3  [["customer_id", 1], ["id", 113], ["LIMIT", 1]]
       (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."order_id" = $1 AND "items"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["order_id", 113], ["id", 307], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      Warehouse Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "warehouses".* FROM "warehouses" 
      INNER JOIN "labeled_products" ON "warehouses"."id" = 
      "labeled_products"."warehouse_id" WHERE "labeled_products"."id" 
      = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 22215], ["LIMIT", 1]]


    Was the item marked for destruction?
    true

    Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE 
    "items"."order_id" = $1 AND "items"."id" = 307  [["order_id",113]]
    (0.2ms)  COMMIT
    Redirected to 
    http://localhost:3000/admin/customers/customer/orders/113
    Completed 302 Found in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

Controller Action:

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @order.update(order_params)
    format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @customer, @order], notice: "Order was successfully updated." }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: [:admin, @customer, @order] }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Some guidance will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add complete code for the update action? And also paste the server log for request when updating the qty of item to zero.

Comment: Hello @JagdeepSingh, I updated my question with complete code for the update action and also added the server log... As I mentioned I tried editing the Item through the Order view and after updating the order the item stays there with the same Qty as before... Everything else (create new, update any other value), works properly... Thanks again!

Comment: And your controller action too please.

Comment: I just added the Update action on the Controller @JagdeepSingh